# myIntent.putExtra during listView onClick

Tags: android, onclick, android-intent

Im trying to attach a picture with and Intent.putExtra, but im not really sure how to display the image when i send it to the next activity.

here is my onClick:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener (new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, bring up Mockactivity.class
      if(position == 1)
      {
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), mockactivity.class);
          myIntent.putExtra("myDrawable", R.drawable.mydrawable);
          startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
      }
```

It will click, and bring up a blank activity that i have named "mockactivity.class" if i take out the "myIntent.putExtra" line, but when that is there it does nothing.
Anyone know how to display that drawable in the next activity that im clicking in to?

Comment: Having or not having the extra should have no bearing on whether the new Activity actually starts or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in the `R` class is an integer representing the actual resource.

In the other `Activity` you need to use something like...

```
int myDrawableId = getIntent().getIntExtra("myDrawable", -1);
```

In this case `-1` is a default value that will be returned if the `Intent` doesn't contain an int extra with that name so test `myDrawableId` to see if it is `-1` before trying to use it.

You should then be able to use `myDrawableId` in the same way as you would use `R.drawable.mydrawable`.

**EDIT:** Using this code...

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(...);
```

...you are trying to find the `ImageView` and not the drawable that is used for its image source. You should be using...

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
```

...where `myImageView` is the `id` of the `ImageView` in your `mockactivity.xml` layout file. If you do that correctly then simply do the following to set the image...

```
view.setImageResource(myDrawableId);
```

Comment: I did that and created an ImageView after that and used findViewById and set it to myDrawableId, but it says the local variable view is not used, and clues to how im not using it?

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mockactivity);
        int myDrawableId = getIntent().getIntExtra("myDrawable", -1);
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(myDrawableId);